# Saving key codes in a variable for use in a function As3

Tags: actionscript-3

I was wondering if there was a way to save  keycodes in a variable that can be used in a function comparing that saved variable with the key that was pressed to trigger the function.

> I.e - I am trying to save a keyCode in a variable for use in a function that checks if the key pressed is the same as the saved keyCode

Comment: Can you describe a little more clearly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a class, [`Keyboard`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html), which has a static list of the keycodes you could want:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

trace(Keyboard.A); // 65
```

Comment: Had none of `Keyboard.A` available, then updated FlashDevelop - there it is. I had to accommodate to this previously :D